# Is there a way to force a Transformer to write spaces as unicode escapes in XML?

Tags: java, xml

When I have a non-breaking-space (&#0A; / &nbsp; in HTML) in text I write to an XML file, I'd like to have it escaped so that I can see in the XML that it's not a regular space.

```
Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
Element element = document.createElement("Foo");
document.appendChild(element);
element.appendChild(document.createTextNode("A\u00A0B"));

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes"); //$NON-NLS-1$

transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(new FileWriter("test.xml")));
```

creates

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Foo>A B</Foo>
```

but I'd like it to be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Foo>A&#A0;B</Foo>
```

Is there any setting I can pass to the Transformer to force this? I don't want to use a CDATA section, because then I'd have to use the '&#A0;' sequence in the Java String and handle that when I display that String.

Comment: This may be off-topic, but... Once you can see your non-breaking spaces, are you planning on doing anything with them - such as replacing them with regular spaces - or is this new version of the XML what you want as the final output?

Comment: I want that as the final output, so that a human looking at the XML or diffs between versions of that XML can clearly see any non-standard blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0+ you can use character maps

```
<xsl:output use-character-map="visible-spaces">
<xsl:character-map name="visible-spaces">
  <xsl:output-character character="&#xa0;" string="&amp;npsp;"/>
  <xsl:output-character character="&#x0a;" string="&amp;nl;"/>
</xsl:character-map>
```

If you generate named entity references in this way, you'll need to ensure that the result document refers to a DTD that defines these entities, which may need some post-processing.

The nearest equivalent in XSLT 1.0 is to use the disable-output-escaping hack, but that means changing every place in the code where you output these characters.

Comment: What would a complete XSLT look like? I tried 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output use-character-map="visible-spaces" />
    <xsl:character-map name="visible-spaces">
        <xsl:output-character character="&#xA0;" string="&amp;#xA0;" />
    </xsl:character-map>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
but that does not seem to change anything. I still get the nbsp in the output.

Comment: Are you sure you are using an XSLT 2.0+ processor? Are you sure you are sending the transformation output to a serializer, rather than say to a DOM tree?

Comment: I am using standard Java 11: 
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource("preserveNbsp.xslt"));
  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
  transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(file));

Shouldn't that complain if it didn't understand XSLT 3.0?

Comment: No, unfortunately, the "forwards compatibility" rules in the XSLT spec say that if you specify version="3.0", an XSLT 1.0 processor will ignore the bits it doesn't understand rather than raising an error. That sort of makes sense for HTML and CSS, it makes less sense for XSLT. And yes, the default processor in the JDK is stuck at XSLT 1.0 level; for something more advanced you need a third-party library.

Comment: D'oh. Thank you for this explanation. As I can't use a third-party-library I'll just String-replace the unicode-blanks with their escape sequences in the final file, if the customer insists...